# bundle update is freezing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm trying to 'bundle update' and its freezing in the middle of fetching deps (I think).  Here is the verbose dump - any ideas?

```
Query Gemcutter Dependency Endpoint API: bones-rcov bones-rubyforge bones-rspec bones-zentest git markaby metaid mab chunky_png fssm term-ansicolor gherkin abstract ZenTest daemons fastthread gem_plugin cgi_multipart_eof_fix rubigen multimap escape_utils ruby-yadis flexmock mocha oniguruma plist eventmachine eventmachine-le http_parser.rb preforker
Fetching from: http://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=bones-rcov,bones-rubyforge,bones-rspec,bones-zentest,git,markaby,metaid,mab,chunky_png,fssm,term-ansicolor,gherkin,abstract,ZenTest,daemons,fastthread,gem_plugin,cgi_multipart_eof_fix,rubigen,multimap,escape_utils,ruby-yadis,flexmock,mocha,oniguruma,plist,eventmachine,eventmachine-le,http_parser.rb,preforker
HTTP Success
Query List: ["trollop", "metaclass", "thoughtbot-shoulda"]
Query Gemcutter Dependency Endpoint API: trollop metaclass thoughtbot-shoulda
Fetching from: http://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=trollop,metaclass,thoughtbot-shoulda
HTTP Success
Query List: []
Unmet Dependencies: ["spicycode-rcov", "tenderlove-frex", "mongodb-mongo"]
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/
Query List: ["spicycode-rcov", "tenderlove-frex", "mongodb-mongo"]
Query Gemcutter Dependency Endpoint API: spicycode-rcov tenderlove-frex mongodb-mongo
Fetching from: http://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=spicycode-rcov,tenderlove-frex,mongodb-mongo
HTTP Success
Query List: []
^[[A^[[A^C
Quitting...
/Users/timpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requirement.rb:114:in `as_list'
/Users/timpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requirement.rb:176:in `to_s'
/Users/timpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requirement.rb:180:in `<=>'
/Users/timpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:148:in `=='
/Users/timpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:148:in `=='
/Users/timpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:15:in `=='
/Users/timpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:180:in `block in resolve'
/Users/timpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:176:in `each'
/Users/timpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:176:in `sort_by'
/Users/timpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:176:in `resolve'
/Users/timpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:222:in `resolve'
/Users/timpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:346:in `block in resolve_requirement'
/Users/timpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `catch'
/Users/timpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `resolve_requirement'
/Users/timpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `block in resolve'
/Users/timpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
/Users/timpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
/Users/timpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@gl
```

Comment: If you're using git, I would maybe do a git reset --hard and try again. Maybe try gem updating that dependency by itself first with --verbose on.

Comment: Also it looks like it's switching to the global gemset to run bundler so maybe try gem install rubygems-bundler in the main rvm you're updating. Not sure if it will help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up stripping down my Gemfile and upgrading one by one and got it to work.  Some sort of deep bug in bundler.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be using rvm and have the wrong version of ruby for a certain gem? Let me know if that helps, glad to help more.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem, and I simply updated bundler to the pre release version.

```
gem install bundler --pre
```

Run bundle update again and bam, should works!